# I want to create an entity X

Tags: spring, hibernate, collections, entities

I want to create an entity X with atributes.
Everything is right except the attribute "permissions" :

```
 public class X implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idNotateur;
@NotEmpty
private String nomNotateur;
@NotEmpty
private String prenomNotateur;
@NotEmpty
private String fonctionNotateur;
@NotEmpty
private String userNotateur;
@NotEmpty
private String passNotateur;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_poste")
private Poste poste;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_dir")
private Direction direction;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="notateur") 
private Collection<Employe> Employes;
private Collection<Long> permissions;


getters & setters ...

 public Collection<Long> getPermissions() {
   return permissions;
 }

 public void setPermissions(Collection<Long> permissions) {
     this.permissions = permissions;
 }



  }
```

Then I came across the following error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: X, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(permissions)]`

So how to solve it?
I'm using Spring MVC Hibenate

Comment: Just curious, I am assuming Employe is your own object and it has a pk, how would be possible for a **Long** object for that collection? Even more, that collection has no the @OneToMany annotation

Comment: I don't think this is what you're intending to do.  Hibernate doesn't (natively) know how to serialize a list of `Long`s into a single database column.

Comment: i want to create entity which has a "list of integer"